# Quantum mechanics: given the eigenstate, find the potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Consider a one-dimensional quantum mechanical system consisting of a particle with mass $m$ in a potential $V(x)$.
The eigenstate are:
$$\psi_{k}(x) = \frac{ika - \tanh(x/a)}{ika+1} \frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\,,$$
for each $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}x\, \psi_k^* (x) \psi_{k'}(x) = \delta (k-k')\,.$$
How can I find the potential $V(x)$?

Comment: How far did you get? Can you show your attempts and where you got stuck?

Comment: Use the Schrödinger's equation, and solve it for $V$...

Comment: I tried, but in that case $V(x)$ is dependent of the eigenvalue $E_k$

Comment: It won't depend on the eigenvalue $E_k$ is you *force* it not to. That is, you choose the relationship between $E_k$ and $k$ so that the $E_k$ and $k$ dependence drops out.

Comment: Ok, got it. If I compute the second derivative of $\psi_k$ It assumes the form of $\psi_k(f(k,a) + g(x))$ where f and g are function. And then the answer is immediate.

Comment: Now I am trying to compute: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} <x|\psi_k> <\psi_k|y> dk$, but the integral contains a term like $e^{ik(x-y)} k^2/(a^2k^2+1)$ and seems divergent...